# Data annotations ErrorMessage error ( using WPF and Entity Framework )

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, xaml, wpf-controls, data-annotations

I'm trying to apply data annotations in my project. I'm using WPF and Entity Framework in my project but when I write for instance

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required!")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

it ignores my error message and instead shows its own error message saying

> "Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   `EntityValidationErrors` property for more details."

What do you recommend for me to pass my own error message?

Thanks in advance.